# Embedding native code in webapps on multiple platforms/browsers

Tags: javascript, web-applications, native-code

I'm thinking of embedding native code (primarily for numerical computations) in a web application. Currently I'm aware of the following technologies for accessing native code from javascript:

- [ActiveX Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) in Internet Explorer on MS Windows
- [Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/) in Chrome/Chromium (Windows, OSX, Linux)
- [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XPCOM) for Firefox (I suppose also for all supported platforms)

Now I have two questions:

1. The list is clearly missing Safari/OSX and mobile browsers (iOS and Android). Are there any similar solutions for these?
2. Are there any efforts/projects to bring these thechnologies together or at least make the development of a cross-platform solution a bit less complicated as it will be anyway? (i.e. let you define your core interfaces/classes and help you generate wrappers for the different approaches)

Comment: You can write Objective-C and Xcode for `iOS`, but I'll shut my mouth before wondering into where I know little. There's also Java (if you consider that "native"), and you omitted Opera. Wouldn't it be more straight-forward to have a service perform the calcs remotely, than it would be authoring all of those browser add-ons?

Comment: And I think that [Common.js](http://www.commonjs.org/) answers your second question, if we're to believe Javascript will one day become first-class.

Comment: +Jared Farrish As much as I personally like Opera, I could live with only supporting "major" browsers. The application requires a great degree of interactivity, sending data to the server, making the computation there and sending the results back wouldn't work (also it would place to many requirements on the server, I'd like the app to be as "client-side" as possible ...)

Comment: any reason why you cant just go pure javascript. ios doesnt support flash.. so embedding native code seems optimistic

Comment: Yeah, it's the little browser that could, right? Is the ubiquity of the browser itself the lure with this project? It seems like JNLP is what you're describing, and I'll be shocked dumb and blind if the browser makers seriously got it together real soon. So, y'know. Browser-based virtual machine could also emerge, and companies like PhoneGap may evolve. Short of that, I'd probably look at the what the people with the money, means and need to solve this, and that would be the finance, trading and other setups that run over the internet.

Comment: Oh, and take a look at Common.js if you haven't, and the multitude of languages that adopt it's proposals. That's where the browser is headed, in my opinion. not Native Client or ActiveX.